# Can I link to individual obj file using #pragma?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, linker

Can I link to individual obj file using #pragma ? I tried `#pragma comment(lib, "disk_file_sink.obj")` but it doesn't seem to work. And it works if I specify this file in Linker/Input/Additional Dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem as yours and I look up many website but I do not get the result so I use an another method to resolve this problem.That was I did.
I use the command *lib* to compact the objs to library. You can use *lib /out:xxx.lib one.obj two.obj* or *lib /out:xxx.lib *.obj*. The command can add to project property.